# Manejo de stock de un inventario con php y mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php7, php5

Tengo una base de datos la cual contiene esas 2 tablas y necesito obtener un reporte del historial de inventario, en el cual se tiene que mostrar la siguiente información de cada movimiento que se ha hecho en una determinada fecha: fecha del movimiento, nombre del producto, documento del movimiento, tipo de movimiento, stock antes del movimiento, cantidad del movimiento y stock después del movimiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplos:

```
Fecha     Producto         Documento  Movimiento  Había Cantidad Hay
25-nov-21 coca cola 250 ml  v001      venta        15     2      13
25-nov-21 papas adobadas    v002      venta        10     1      9
26-nov-21 coca cola 250 ml  v004      venta        13     3      10
27-nov-21 papas limón       v005      venta        14     2      12
28-nov-21 coca cola 250 ml  c001      compra       10     5      15
```

Con las tablas que muestro se puede obtener el reporte que quiero y si es así como seria?? O me hace falta agregar más tablas o agregar campos a las tablas que ya tengo??

Estoy trabajando con PHP como lenguaje de programación

Comment: Corrigeme si me equivoco, las tablas son `producto` y `movimiento` ¿verdad? Entendiendo que movimiento es una `venta` o una `compra` que disminuirá o incrementará el `stock`.

Comment: @AldahirRuizValdez es correcto, una tabla se llama producto y la otra movimiento. Y así es una venta disminuye el stock y una compra lo incrementa

Comment: Para empezar la tabla `movimiento` deberia de tener un `producto_id` relacionado como `FK` para saber cual es el producto que se esta añadiendo. 1 movimiento tiene 1 producto, pero 1 producto tiene muchos movimientos. Te recomendaria empezar por ahí. A tu tabla `movimiento` añadir como FK el campo `producto_id`

Comment: Bueno si te fijas la tabla movimiento tiene un campo llamado id_producto y este actua como FK

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta, deja y te explico la lógica que necesitas implementar. Ya que para darte todo el código sería complicado.

Comment: Que tiene que ver php con todo esto, si es un problema pura y exclusivamente de base de datos? o vas a resolverlo del lado de php haciendo dos select simples y luego haciendo los calculos del otro lado?

Comment: @gbianchi pues solo para recalcar que lenguaje de programación estoy usando para esta aplicación, y la verdad no se me ocurre si este problema se puede resolver desde la base de datos o con php o con ambos

Comment: @AldahirRuizValdez claro, espero tu explicación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta sería algo asi...

```
SELECT movimientos.fecha, productos.id, movimientos.documento,
movimientos.movimiento, movimientos.stock_inicial, movimientos.cantidad,movimientos.stock_final
FROM productos, movimientos WHERE productos.id = movimientos.producto_id and movimientos.fecha = TU_FECHA
```

Ahora, tendrias que agregar a tu tabla movimientos, dos campos `stock_inicial, y stock_final` Estos serian el `stock` antes del movimiento, y el `stock` despues del movimiento. Tambien te recomendaria añadir a tu tabla `productos` el campo `nombre` que creo que no lo tiene, asi en lugar de `producto.id` pones `producto.nombre`

Ahora, si lo que quieres es mostrar todos los productos ordenados por fecha.

```
SELECT movimientos.fecha, productos.id, movimientos.documento,
movimientos.movimiento, movimientos.stock_inicial, movimientos.cantidad,movimientos.stock_final
FROM productos, movimientos WHERE productos.id = movimientos.producto_id ORDER BY movimientos.fecha DESC
```

Comment: Ahora los valores de stock_inicial y stock_final se guardarían al momento de registrar el movimiento?? Es decir antes de hacer el registro del movimiento tendría que poner como stock_inicial lo que tengo de stock_actual y después haría el calculo stock_actual - cantidad para ese resultado ponerlo como stock_final??

Comment: Exacto, eso ya es en la logica de PHP. Tendrias que hacer una consulta previa antes de guardarlo, para saber cuanto hay en ´stock´ actualmente. Y, dependiendo el tipo de movimiento, aumentas o disminuyes el stock. Y ese valor, lo guardas como `stock_final`. Cosa que tambien deberias alterar en la tabla `productos` y asignarle el nuevo `stock`.

Comment: Hay otras formas de hacerlo, manejandonos solo con el historial de movimientos, pero a mi parecer es mas engorroso.

Comment: Y si se puede podrías decirme como sería con alguna otra forma como lo mencionas??

Comment: Tendrias que hacer una consulta al estado anterior, osea, consultar cual fue el ultimo movimiento que se realizó para ese producto, ahi tendrias el `stock final`, y trabajarias con ese stock. En cuyo caso, el campo `stock` de la tabla `productos` ya no seria necesario. El problema es la busqueda que si tienes supongamos, 10 mil movimientos, demoraria mucho mas que solo buscando en la tabla productos (que no tendra muchos productos)  y consultando el `stock actual`